# How to navigate to other screen from navigation drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, drawer

i have tried in the following way but it is not working please tell me the solutions

```
import 'package:book_recommendation_app/about.dart';
import 'package:book_recommendation_app/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future<void> main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);



  void onTap(menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem) {
      case 'item1':
        print('item1 clicked');
        break;
      case 'item2':
        print('item2 clicked');
        break;
      case 'item3':
        print('item3 clicked');
        break;
    }
  }



  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var menuItems = <String>['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Book Reccomendation Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            PopupMenuButton<String>(
                onSelected: onTap,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return menuItems.map((String choice) {
                    return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                      child: Text(choice),
                      value: choice,
                    );
                  }).toList();
                })
          ],
        ),
        body: searchBar(),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              const DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Item 1'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('About us'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutUs()),
                  );
                  Navigator.pop(context);

                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Book Reccomendation Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

`// This widget is the root of your application.`
`@override`
`Widget build(BuildContext context) {`
`var menuItems = <String>['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];`
`return MaterialApp(`
`title: 'Book Reccomendation Demo',`
`home: Scaffold(`
`appBar: AppBar(`
`title: Text('Home'),`
`actions: <Widget>[`
`PopupMenuButton<String>(`
`onSelected: onTap,`
`itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {`
`return menuItems.map((String choice) {`
`return PopupMenuItem<String>(`
`child: Text(choice),`
`value: choice,`
`);`
`}).toList();`
`})`
`],`
`),`
`body: searchBar(),`
`drawer: Drawer(`
`child: ListView(`
`padding: EdgeInsets.zero,`
`children: [`
`const DrawerHeader(`
`decoration: BoxDecoration(`
`color: Colors.blue,`
`),`
`child: Text('Drawer Header'),`
`),`
`ListTile(`
`title: const Text('Item 1'),`
`onTap: () {`
`Navigator.pop(context);`
`},`
`),`
`ListTile(`
`title: const Text('About us'),`
`onTap: () {`
`Navigator.push(`
`context,`
`MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutUs()),`
`);`
`Navigator.pop(context);`

```
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  // home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Book Reccomendation Demo Home Page'),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 2):

Pop the drawer before pushing to new screen,
Like

```
Navigator.pop(context);
Navigator.push(context,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutUs(),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not call Navigator.pop(context) immediately afther calling Navigator.push. Because for me it looks like your currently pushing to the next screen, but immediately popping again so that it will never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

In this ListTile

```
ListTile(
            title: const Text('About us'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutUs()),
              );
              Navigator.pop(context);

            },
          ),
```

You use `Navigator.Push(context,MaterialPageRout(builder: (context) => AboutUs()));`
then you use `Navegator.pop(context);`
that means you push a new screen then you closed it and here is the problem

you need just to remove this line `Navigator.pop(context);`

Comment: By removing `Navigator.pop(context);`, the drawer will no longer close. The answer from @Abhishek will close the drawer and navigate to the new route properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) too for navigate your pages in easier way if you don't want to go with `MaterialPageRoute`.

```
ListTile(
        title: const Text('About us'),
        onTap: () {
          Get.to(AboutUs());
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
```